# Javascript Logical OR and Objects

Tags: javascript, object, logical-operators

Can someone explain everything that's happening in a statement like this:

```
POJO.someProperty = POJO.someProperty || {}
```

Is this checking for undefined then simply assigning an empty object if undefined = true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) in javasript can return non boolean values. The [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_(.7C.7C)) operator will return the first [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value it finds in the operands. The Logical AND will return the first [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, or the last operand if all other operands are [truhty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values.
>   When they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and ||
>   operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands,
>   so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may
>   return a non-Boolean value.

- 1 || 0 -> 1
- 1 && '' -> ''

So when your code is evaluated if `POJO.someProperty` is undefined then the operator will process the second operator which is an empty object(which is a truthy value) so that value will be returned and assigned back to `someProperty`.

Why is it used, it is used normally to escape the property not defined error. Assume you are trying to access a property of `POJO.someProperty`, like `POJO.someProperty.somekey` but then if `POJO.someProperty` is undefined then you will get an error. But here if it is undefined then we are assigning an empty object so `POJO.someProperty.somekey` will return undefined not an error.

Comment: So, its best to use this pattern when accessing the properties of an object that might not exist? I would have never known that on my own! Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is checking to see if `POJO.someProperty` has a truthy value. If it does, then nothing happens. If the property is falsy, then the property is assigned an empty object literal.

Falsy means one of several things:

1. A `false` literal
2. The number 0
3. `null`
4. `undefined`
5. An empty string

If the property has any of these values, it will be reassigned to an empty object.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I did not know you could actually assign a property based on the results of the "||" evaluation. I have only used it in the context of conditional evaluation.

Comment: Yes, `||` will return the first (LHS) expression if it evaluates to something truthy. Else it will evaluate the second (RHS) expression and return that.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, as in C, the value of an assignment expression is the value of the right-side operand. In the example you provided, the expression on the right side of the assignment is evaluated before the assignment happens. Because it's a logical OR, it will evaluate to an object literal `{}` if `POJO.someProperty` is falsy.

You might see assignment expressions used like this in other places too (notice the single equal sign in the `if` expression):

```
var x = 1;
var y = 0;
if (y = x) {
    // This block executes because x is 1 (also, y is now 1)
}
```